# Sobel edge detection creates noise

Tags: java, computer-vision, bufferedimage, sobel

I tried to implement the Sobel edge detection in java. 
It kind of works but I get a lot of seemingly random noise...

I loaded the image as BufferedImages and converted those to greyscaleimages first (via an algorithm i found online). After that I calculate the edges in x and y direction.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Sobel {

    static int [] sobel_x =     {1, 0,  -1, 
                                2,  0,  -2,
                                1,  0,  -1};

    static int [] sobel_y =     {1, 2,  1, 
                                0,  0,  0,
                                -1, -2, -1};




    public static void main(String argc[]) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage imgIn = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpeg"));
        BufferedImage imgGrey = greyscale(imgIn);
        ImageIO.write(imgGrey, "PNG", new File("greyscale.jpg"));

        BufferedImage edgesX = edgeDetection(imgGrey, sobel_x);
        ImageIO.write(edgesX, "PNG", new File("edgesX.jpg"));

        BufferedImage edgesY = edgeDetection(imgGrey, sobel_y);
        ImageIO.write(edgesY, "PNG", new File("edgesY.jpg"));

        BufferedImage sobel = sobel(edgesX,edgesY);
        ImageIO.write(sobel, "PNG", new File("sobel.jpg"));

    }


    private static BufferedImage sobel (BufferedImage edgesX, BufferedImage edgesY){

        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(edgesX.getWidth(), edgesX.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        int height = result.getHeight();
        int width = result.getWidth();
         for(int x = 0; x < width ; x++){
           for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
               int tmp = Math.abs(edgesX.getRGB(x, y) + Math.abs(edgesY.getRGB(x, y)));
               result.setRGB(x, y, tmp);
           }
        }
        return result; 
    }

    private static BufferedImage edgeDetection(BufferedImage img, int[] kernel){
       int height = img.getHeight();
       int width = img.getWidth();

       BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width -1, height -1, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
       for(int x = 1; x < width -1 ; x++){
           for(int y = 1; y < height - 1; y++){
               int [] tmp = {img.getRGB(x-1, y-1),img.getRGB(x, y-1),img.getRGB(x+1, y-1),img.getRGB(x-1, y),img.getRGB(x, y),img.getRGB(x+1, y),img.getRGB(x-1, y+1),img.getRGB(x, y+1),img.getRGB(x+1, y+1)};
               int value = convolution (kernel, tmp);
               result.setRGB(x,y, value);
           }
       }
       return result;
   }


   private static int convolution (int [] kernel, int [] pixel){
       int result = 0; 

       for (int i = 0; i < pixel.length; i++){
           result += kernel[i] * pixel[i];
       }

       return result / 9;
   }


   private static BufferedImage greyscale(BufferedImage img){

     //get image width and height
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();

        //convert to grayscale
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
          for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            int p = img.getRGB(x,y);

            int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
            int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
            int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
            int b = p&0xff;

            //calculate average
            int avg = (r+g+b)/3;

            //replace RGB value with avg
            p = (a<<24) | (avg<<16) | (avg<<8) | avg;

            img.setRGB(x, y, p);
          }
        }
       return img;
   }
}
```

And this is an example of the noise I'm talking about:

An image of Lena :

[image]

I don't know why I get all this noise.
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the following changes:

in convolution take the absolute value

```
   private static int convolution (int [] kernel, int [] pixel){
       int result = 0; 

       for (int i = 0; i < pixel.length; i++){
           result += kernel[i] * pixel[i];
       }

       return (int)(Math.abs(result) / 9);
   }
```

in edgeDetection apply the value to all three channels

```
    private static BufferedImage edgeDetection(BufferedImage img, int[] kernel){
       int height = img.getHeight();
       int width = img.getWidth();

       BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width -1, height -1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       for(int x = 1; x < width -1 ; x++){
           for(int y = 1; y < height - 1; y++){
               int [] tmp = {img.getRGB(x-1, y-1)&0xff,img.getRGB(x, y-1)&0xff,img.getRGB(x+1, y-1)&0xff,
               img.getRGB(x-1, y)&0xff,img.getRGB(x, y)&0xff,img.getRGB(x+1, y)&0xff,img.getRGB(x-1, y+1)&0xff,
               img.getRGB(x, y+1)&0xff,img.getRGB(x+1, y+1)&0xff};
               int value = convolution (kernel, tmp);
               result.setRGB(x,y, 0xff000000|(value<<16)|(value<<8)|value);
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
```

And finally declare the images as INT_RGB type

```
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(edgesX.getWidth(), edgesX.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width -1, height -1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Comment: I find it quite costly to change all three channels. Would it be possible to convert the image into a 2d 0-255 greyscale image and only change values at x and y?

Comment: it will be a much more complicated effort if you go with getRaster etc but it will be faster - for immediate results I dont see anything unless you mean to create an array a[][]. put up another question if you try it

Comment: you can also use this result.setRGB(x,y, value); which will create blue images